# How to add a custom query in JHipster?

Tags: angularjs, spring, jhipster

I am learning to use JHipster and can't figure out how to use create a custom query.

In my project I have `Orders` table with `DeliveryDay` and `Week` fields and want to show only orders for current day of the week. DeliveryDay and Week is `int` with values (1-7 and 0-2)

So in `OrdersRepository.java` I added custom query like this:

```
public interface OrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<Orders,Long> {

Page<Orders> findByDeliveryDayAndWeek(int weekday, int week, pageable);
```

in `OrdersResource.java` i added this one:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/today",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<Orders>> getOrdersForToday(Pageable pageable)
        throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Orderss");
        Page<Orders> page = ordersRepository.findByDeliveryDayAndWeek(1, 0, pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/today");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I also added `today.html` (copied `orders.html`) and today.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fruitcrmApp')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('today', {
                parent: 'entity',
                url: '/today',
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                    pageTitle: 'fruitcrmApp.orders.home.title'
                },
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'scripts/app/custom/today.html',
                        controller: 'OrdersController'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('orders');
                        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('global');
                        return $translate.refresh();
                    }]
                }
            })

    });
```

and add `today.js` in the `index.html`

My `orders.controller.js` looks like this (generated by JHipster)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fruitcrmApp')
    .controller('OrdersController', function ($scope, $state, Orders, OrdersSearch, ParseLinks) {

        $scope.orderss = [];
        $scope.predicate = 'id';
        $scope.reverse = true;
        $scope.page = 1;
        $scope.loadAll = function() {
            Orders.query({page: $scope.page - 1, size: 20, sort: [$scope.predicate + ',' + ($scope.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc'), 'id']}, function(result, headers) {
                $scope.links = ParseLinks.parse(headers('link'));
                $scope.totalItems = headers('X-Total-Count');
                $scope.orderss = result;
            });
        };
        $scope.loadPage = function(page) {
            $scope.page = page;
            $scope.loadAll();
        };
        $scope.loadAll();


        $scope.search = function () {
            OrdersSearch.query({query: $scope.searchQuery}, function(result) {
                $scope.orderss = result;
            }, function(response) {
                if(response.status === 404) {
                    $scope.loadAll();
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.refresh = function () {
            $scope.loadAll();
            $scope.clear();
        };

        $scope.clear = function () {
            $scope.orders = {
                details: null,
                orderDate: null,
                firstDelivery: null,
                isActive: false,
                id: null
            };
        };
    });
```

Now I can access `http://localhost:3000/#/today` but it shows all data from `Orders` what I did wrong? How to use my own method from `OrdersRepository.java`?

I tried to search for examples but didn't found any relevant. What are the needed steps I missed? Link for some tutorial where it is covered will be great if answer will be to long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a new angular service for your `today` API endpoint. Something like this, called `orders-today.service.js`:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fruitcrmApp')
    .factory('OrdersToday', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/orders/today', {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true}
        });
    });
```

Then in your `orders.controller.js` file, you need to inject your new OrdersToday service:

```
.controller('OrdersController', function ($scope, $state, Orders, OrdersSearch, OrdersToday, ParseLinks) {
```

When you want to get the list of today's orders, you need to use `OrdersToday.query` just like you used `Orders.query` in the example you pasted.

You will probably want to create a `OrdersTodayController` with references to `OrdersToday`, and use that in `today.js` instead of `OrdersController`.